# Errors when trying to display an image from ActiveStorage in Rails 5.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spree, rails-activestorage

I am working on a Rails app using Rails 5.2 and Ruby 2.3.7 and want to attach an image to my Event object, using Active Storage.

Here are the main steps I've taken

In config/environments/development.rb I confirmed that: config.active_storage.service = :local

Files

event.rb I've added this line:
has_one_attached :event_image

events_controller.rb I have the :event_image attribute whitelisted in event_params

events/_form.html.erb I have set a form_for to upload an image

```
<%= f.label :event_images %>
<%= f.file_field :event_image %>
```

events/index.html.erb I try to display the image with

```
<% if event.event_image.attached? %>
<%= image_tag event.event_image %>
<% end %>
```

Error: Can't resolve image into URL: undefined method `attachment_url' for :0x00007fca5dcef8b8>

```
<% if event.event_image.attached? %>
<%= image_tag url_for(event.event_image) %>
<% end %>
```

Error: undefined method `attachment_path' for Class:0x00007fca5e0109c0>:0x00007fca5dacefe8>

I have 
confirmed that active_storage_attachments and active_storage_blobs exist in my database and the attachments are saved there

Any suggestions would be very much appreciated.  From all my googling it would seem that this should work

Comment: Do you have in your `config/environments/development.rb` this line: `config.default_url_options = { host: "localhost:3000" }` ?

Comment: Don't use `image_tag` for this. Its a helper thats meant to serve images through the assets pipeline. Instead just manually create the tag with `<img src="<%= url_for(event.event_image) %>">` or `tag :img, src: url_for(event.event_image)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Further update on this issue.  I repeated the same steps in my own application and it worked fine.  This only occurs when working with an application that is using Spree

Answer (score 6):

When working with Spree, you should prefix the `url_for` method with: `main_app.url_for`:

```
image_path(main_app.url_for(event.event_image))
```

This is valid with Spree v3.6.5 and v3.6.6, not sure about other versions.

Comment: I was seeing an error like this

`<pre>ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method attachment_path for #<#<Class:0x00007fa21a829b78>:0x00007fa219d607f0>):`

**And specifying main_app worked for me.**

However, I still trying to figure out, how I can use active storage transformation to show preview of the file instead of showing the big one.

Answer (score 1):

```
image_path(main_app.url_for(event.event_image))
```

It works for me on my spree 4.0 extension.